# load JSON response from SharePoint-Javascript form

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, sharepoint

first of all, sorry for my so confusing english, i'll try to explain my problem as well i can. 
i have a WCF service running in an azure web app. the service receives a parameter and shows some HR data in JSON. in debugging and production, the service runs well. also, i have a custom sharepoint list form that (in a good scenario) receives the JSON response and shows the data.
in the past, a hired company deployed this solution and worked well, until the server that hosted the WCF service was closed. now i'm deploying a new service and i would like to connect the service with the form. i tried to change the WCF route in the ASPX custom form using sharepoint designer but doesn't work when load. i don't want to change the form apprearance, amount of textbox or their order. only i want to show the JSON response in the form

this is the javascript code in the custom form. this code worked before the company closed the original server, absolutely nothing of this code has been changed, only the wcf address

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
        function Initialize() {
            console.log(_spPageContextInfo);
            var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": "http://mytestserver.azurewebsites.net/Service.svc/ObtainEmp/" + _spPageContextInfo.userEmail,
              "method": "GET"
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              var person = response.ObtainEmpResult;
              $('#nameemp').text(person.Name + ' ' + person.FirstName + ' ' + person.SecondName);
              var CardCode = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Identification");
              $(CardCode).val(person.Identification);
              $(CardCode).prop('readonly', true);
              var numberemp = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Employee Number");
              $(numberemp).val(person.EmpCode);
              $(numberemp).prop('readonly', true);
              var position = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Position");
              $(position).val(person.Position);
              $(position).prop('readonly', true);
              var dept = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Dept");
              $(dept).val(person.Dept);
              $(dept).prop('readonly', true);
              $('#cumulativedays').text(person.ObtainedVacationDays);
              $('#avdays').text(person.AvailableDays);
            });
        }
        function getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(tagName, identifier, title) {
            var len = identifier.length;
            var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var tempString = tags[i].id;
                if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" || tempString.indexOf(identifier) == tempString.length - len)) {
                    return tags[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function PreSaveAction(){
          var CardCode = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Identification");
          $(CardCode).prop('readonly', false);
          var numberemp = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Employee Number");
          $(numberemp).prop('readonly', false);
          var position = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Position");
          $(position).prop('readonly', false);
          var dept = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input", "", "Dept");
          $(dept).prop('readonly', false);
          return true;
        }
</script>
```

this is the IService code in C#

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ObtainEmp/{pMail}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        Employee ObtainEmp(string pMail);
    }
```

This is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HR.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="HR.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

i don't know a lot about javascript sharepoint forms and i would like to learn and solve this problem. as i said, the WCF service works fine in production (hosted in azure), so the problem maybe is in the javascript code.

appreciate every help. thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried posting the wcf URL in a browser to see if it resolves ?

Comment: Are you trying to talk to WCF service from javascript? Little piece of advice - don't do that without a library, it will give you an immense amount of headaches, best thing I can suggest is to call an api on your c side and pass it through from there

Comment: yes, and it works. obvoiusly, i changed the url in this post for security reasons, but the original url resolves

Comment: @MarkDavies how I do that?? I'm a newbie in this area

Comment: take a look at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/consuming-wcf-service-using-javascript/

Comment: What is the error detail? now that the service can return the Json data, why doesn’t it work? Alternatively, the data format is not correct? Besides, your service doesn’t support HTTPS protocol, which is the default support in Azure Web APP. It requires the webhttpbinding with Transport security mode and applies it to the service endpoint.

Comment: @AbrahamQian there is no error detail. 
the only fault is that the wcf service should send the JSON data to the javascript code, and for some reason it doesn't. The form stays empty. When I debug the web service, it shows me the data in the browser as it should, but the form does not. Now, I already changed the web.config file, so my service now supports https

Comment: Try to debug the Javascript code in the browser to see if response has the right data.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: thank you all, i've found my error. look at this `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cabrrhh.azurewebsites.net/service.svc/ObtainEmp/myparameter' from origin 'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` i've reading about this, it means that i have to enable CORS policies in my azure web app

Comment: @AbrahamQian thank you for the tip. I saw the error and enable CORS in the azure web app. Now the form works well.